# Pattern Matching on Disjunction

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given the following:

```
scala> val err: \/[String, Boolean \/ Int] = -\/("bad")
err: scalaz.\/[String,scalaz.\/[Boolean,Int]] = -\/(bad)
```

I wrote a function that takes a `\/[String, Boolean \/ Int]` and returns a `Boolean \/ Int`:

```
scala> def f(x: \/[String, Boolean \/ Int]): \/[Boolean, Int] = x match {
     |       case -\/(_) => -\/(false)
     |       case \/-(y) => y
     | }
f: (x: scalaz.\/[String,scalaz.\/[Boolean,Int]])scalaz.\/[Boolean,Int]
```

It appears to work as expected:

```
scala> f(err)
res6: scalaz.\/[Boolean,Int] = -\/(false)

scala> f(\/-(\/-(5))
     | )
res7: scalaz.\/[Boolean,Int] = \/-(5)
```

Is there a more concise, idiomatic scalaz way to do this?

Comment: Looking at the documentation you should be able to use `valueOr`: `x.valueOr(-\/(false))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def f(x: \/[String, Boolean \/ Int]) = x.getOrElse(-\/(false))
```